# Using Ruby, how do I convert all array values to a given type?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to convert fixnums to strings. My solution is:

```
arr.map {|a| a.to_s}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Your solution is about as clear (good) as it gets, IMHO.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
arr.map(&:to_s)
```

This uses a spiffy new feature in Ruby >= 1.8.7, the ["symbol to proc" shortcut](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/7/symbol-to-proc-shorthand), and is equivalent to the code in your question.

Comment: I hadn't seen this before. What is the operator called? Do you have a link to documentation for the feature?

Comment: @hambend, Great questions.  Answer amended.

Comment: BTW: while this was only added to the Ruby core library in 1.9 and backported to 1.8.7, it has been available in ActiveSupport, Facets and many other Ruby extension libraries for *ages* before that.