# How to use percent notation to make an array of integers in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

In ruby you can use percent notation to easily make an array of strings:

```
[14] pry(main)> %w(some cats ran far)
=> ["some", "cats", "ran", "far"]
```

Using a method found in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319602/using-ruby-how-do-i-convert-all-array-values-to-a-given-type) I was able to make an array of strings using percent notation and then converting them into Fixnums later:

```
[15] pry(main)> %w(1 2 3).map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

But I'd really like to be able to do something like

```
%i(1 2 3) #=> [1 2 3]
```

Is this possible? Thanks :)

Comment: No, that isn't possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As cremno said, no that is not possible.

If you want strictly a range of integers, such as 1 through 10, the best method will be

```
(1..10).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But if you want to specify exact integers I would do this

```
%w(1 5 10).map{|i| i.to_i}
# => [1, 5, 10]
```

But at that point I don't know why you wouldn't just do this directly...

```
[1, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this.

```
%i(1 2 3).map(&:to_s).map { |i| Integer(i) } #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a range seems like it might be the easiest:

```
[26] pry(main)> (1..3).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3]
```